# Slow Down Autocomplete with Winforms ComboBox

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0, combobox

I am using the AutoCompleteMode property of SuggestAppend on my Winforms ComboBox. It is working fine, but the user has asked if there is a way to slow down the autocomplete when typing into the combobox.

For example, if you have 2 items in the combobox: **red** and **dark blue**
When you select the combobox and start typing **r e d** without pausing at all it works fine. But if you pause for even a second, say **r e** pause for a second then type **d**, it will highlight dark blue.

I would like to just slow it down a little bit. Some of my users are not very computer savvy so they need a little more time to type.

If I am not clear enough please let me know and I will think of another way to explain it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: MS documentation doesn't hint at more advanced options. Probably will be forced to write your own autocomplete routine or recruit and existing one, obviously one with more options.